# Any way to add a wildcard or strip out a forced addition to an ID (AJAX adds a --XXXXX to an ID once search button is clicked) using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Using Drupal views site search function on a page.
Problem is, it displays the reset button which links to the actual site search page instead of just loading the page.
I need to place my own reset button which reloads the page instead of redirecting to the main site search page.

I have placed my own reset button next to the search button which just reloads the page for the user like so:

```
window.onload = reset;

function reset(){
    node = document.getElementById('edit-submit-site-search');
    node.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<button class="button js-form-submit form-submit btn-danger btn icon-before" type="submit" onClick="window.location.reload();"><span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Reset</button>');
}
```

Problem is, once a user clicks on the search button, Drupal adds something to the search button, such as this: `--_STT5p3OI_4` (which makes my getElementByID up top now useless as the reset button goes away when we actually need it)

Anyone know how I can fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Could you give it a class and use `querySelector` instead of `getElementById`?

Comment: You can use a pattern in a selector: `[id^="edit-submit-site-search"]` matches any ID beginning with that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Unfortunately, it's automatically driven and I can't add a class in the drupal view. Please excuse my noobness, but how would I go about using this: [id^="edit-submit-site-search"]. I'm just a beginner and I'm not sure how to add that to my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ["attribute starts with"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) query selector.

```
function reset(){
    node = document.querySelector('[id^="edit-submit-site-search"]');
    node.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<button class="button js-form-submit form-submit btn-danger btn icon-before" type="submit" onClick="window.location.reload();"><span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Reset</button>');
}
```

Comment: First, thank you Barmar. I appreciate your time. I know you're not here to do my work for me. I do realize what you have done, so thank you for your help. While this did indeed place the button right where it's supposed to be, when I performed a search, the reset button disappeared. I'm thinking it's because it's an ajax search....meaning it didn't refresh/reload the page? After searching for awhile, I'm not sure if anything can be done about that. But then again, I'm just getting started in my programming journey. Would you know? Thanks again.

Comment: It sounds like either the search code is reloading the page instead of using AJAX, or it displays the results in a way that overwrites the reset button. You should post a new question that shows how you do the search.